# Header fields in MessageContract class are not available in Windows Phone application

Tags: wcf, windows-phone, messagecontract

I have a WCF service. In that service I have defined class marked MessageContract attribute:

```
[MessageContract]
public class RemoteFileInfo : IDisposable
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public string FileName;

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public long Length;

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public Picture Picture;

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public System.IO.Stream FileByteStream;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (FileByteStream != null)
        {
            FileByteStream.Close();
            FileByteStream = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I have problem with fields marked MessageHeader attribute.
In WPF app (client) all fields are visible but when I use this service in Windows Phone app, fields marked MessageHeader are not visible. Only body fields are available. Is any possibility that header fields also be available?

Answer (score 1):

WEll, seems that WP not support MessageContract directly. So, you can see the solution [in another thread on this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942113/silverlight-is-not-liking-my-wcf-messagecontract-why) :)